# How can I perform semi-supervised learning for Random forest algorithm in R language?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, semi-supervised-learning

I want to train random forest by semi-supervised learning. And I have figured out a co-training framework for that, but I need to extract each tree and corresponding bootstrapped training dataset from the fitted random forest model. Is there a way to do that in R?

Comment: If using the `randomForest` package, then the whole forest is in `fit$forest` and the samples used are in `fit$inbag`.

Comment: Thank you. I want to change the bootstrapped training data for each tree, and retrain the tree classifier. Do you know whether this can be done with the package?

Comment: That is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this right, are you trying to predict new unknown cases after building the model?

Comment: Based on other's idea about semi-supervised learning algorithm for RF,  I need iteratively extract each tree from trained RF, and retrain the tree using an updated training dataset. Of course, after retraining the tree, it will be used to predict new cases.

Comment: Or do you know where can I find semi-supervised RF code? Because I am not very familiar with programing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by retrain the tree? To adjust an existing tree based on new data? This is wierd, I have never hear of this.

Comment: Yes. This is what some semi-supervised learning algorithm did (see for example Leistner et al. (2009). Semi-supervised random forests. ICCV2009.).

Comment: I don't think this has caught up with R yet. There is one package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSSL/RSSL.pdf which has some semi-supervised algorithms, but not RF.